# Having trouble parsing a .CSV file into a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I've done some simple .csv parsing in python but have a new file structure that's giving me trouble.   The input file is from a spreadsheet converted into a .CSV file.   Here is an example of the input:
[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doCUt.png)

Each set can have many layouts, and each layout can have many layers.  Each layer has only one layer and name.

Here is the code I am using to parse it in. I suspect it's a logic/flow control problem because I've parsed things in before, just not this deep.  The first header row is skipped via code. Any help appreciated!

```
import csv
import pprint

def import_layouts_schema(layouts_schema_file_name = 'C:\\layouts\\LAYOUT1.csv'):

    class set_template:

    def __init__(self):

        self.set_name    =''
        self.layout_name =''
        self.layer_name  =''
        self.obj_name    =''

     def check_layout(st, row, layouts_schema):

        c=0

        if st.layout_name == '':

            st.layer_name = row[c+2]
            st.obj_name = row[c+3]

            layer = {st.layer_name : st.obj_name}

            layout = {st.layout_name : layer}
            layouts_schema.update({st.set_name : layout})

        else:

            st.layout_name = row[c+1]
            st.layer_name = row[c+2]
            st.obj_name = row[c+3]

            layer = {st.layer_name : st.obj_name}

            layout = {st.layout_name : layer}

            layouts_schema.update({st.set_name : layout})

        return layouts_schema


    def layouts_schema_parsing(obj_list_raw1): #, location_categories, image_schema, set_location):
         #------ init -----------------------------------
         skipfirst = True
         c = 0
         firstrow = True
         layouts_schema = {}
         end_flag = ''
         st = set_template()
         #---------- start parsing here -----------------
         print('Now parsing layouts schema list')
         for row in obj_list_raw1:

             #print ('This is the row: ', row)
             if skipfirst==True:
                 skipfirst=False
                 continue
             if row[c] != '':
                 st.set_name = row[c]
                 st.layout_name = row[c+1]
                 st.layer_name = row[c+2]
                 st.obj_name = row[c+3]

                 print('FOUND A NEW SET.  SET details below:')
                 print('Set name:', st.set_name, 'Layout name:', st.layout_name, 'Layer name:', st.layer_name, 'Object name:', st.obj_name)
                 if firstrow == True:
                     print('First row of layouts import!')
                     layer = {st.layer_name : st.obj_name}
                     layout = {st.layout_name : layer}
                     layouts_schema = {st.set_name : layout}



                firstrow = False

                check_layout(st, row, layouts_schema)

                continue
            elif firstrow == False:
                print('Not the first row of layout import')

                layer = {st.layer_name : st.obj_name}
                layout = {st.layout_name : layer}
                layouts_schema.update({st.set_name : layout})


                check_layout(st, row, layouts_schema)

        return layouts_schema

     #begin subroutine main
     layouts_schema_file_name ='C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\RAY\\layout_schemas\\ANIBOT_LAYOUTS_SCHEMA.csv'
     full_path_to_file = layouts_schema_file_name 
     print('============ Importing LAYOUTS schema from: ', full_path_to_file , ' ==============')
     openfile = open(full_path_to_file)
     reader_ob = csv.reader(openfile)
     layout_list_raw1 = list(reader_ob)
     layouts_schema = layouts_schema_parsing(layout_list_raw1)
     print('=========== End of layouts schema import =========')

     return layouts_schema



 layouts_schema = import_layouts_schema()
```

Feel free to throw any part away that doesn't work.  I suspect I've inside my head a little bit here.   A for loop or another while loop may do the trick.  Ultimately I just want to parse the file into a dict with the same key structure shown.  i.e. the final dict's first line would look like:

{'RESTAURANT': {'RR_FACING1': {'BACKDROP': 'restaurant1'}}}

And the rest on from there.  Ultimately I am goign to use this key structure and the dict for other purposes.   Just can't get the parsing down!

Comment: This code is a bit messy and you might not get the help you need here. Perhaps the code-review site might be a better fit for this. You look like you've made a good attempt at getting this working, but it might be too messy to get fixed here on StackOverflow

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/   EDIT: They might only review working code so I'm not sure if this will work either.. but maybe someone else can comment and let you know?

Comment: Hey, thanks.  I think "a bit messy" is an understatement.  I was kinda tired when I wrote this and it's based off a quick and messy brute force if-then branch I wrote for a simpler set of data.  I think I may need to throw this code out completely, but the one to many relationship part is the same as described above.   Maybe I'll do this a bunch of ways in a sandbox and submit one to a the code review thing if I still can't get it working.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wouaw, that's a lot of code !

Maybe try something simpler :

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    keys = f.readline().split(';') # assuming ";" is your csv fields separator
    for line in f:
        vals = line.split(';')
        d = dict(zip(keys, vals))
        print(d)
```

Then either make a better data file (without blanks), or have the parser remembering the previous values.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @AK47 that the code review site may be the better approach, I received so many help from SO that I'll try to give back a little: IMHO you are overthinking the problem. Please find below an approach that should get you in the right direction and doesn't even require converting from Excel to CSV (I like the `xlrd` module, it's very easy to use). If you already have a CSV, just exchange the loop in the `process_sheet()` function. Basically, I just store the last value seen for "SET" and "LAYOUT" and if they are different (and not empty), I set the new value. Hope that helps. And yes, you should think about a better data structure (redundancy is not always bad, if you can avoid empty cells :-) ).

```
import xlrd

def process_sheet(sheet : xlrd.sheet.Sheet):
    curr_set = ''
    curr_layout = ''
    for rownum in range(1, sheet.nrows):
        row = sheet.row(rownum)
        set_val = row[0].value.strip()
        layout_val = row[1].value.strip()
        if set_val != '' and set_val != curr_set:
            curr_set = set_val
        if layout_val != '' and layout_val != curr_layout:
            curr_layout = layout_val
        result = {curr_set: {curr_layout: {row[2].value: row[3].value}}}
        print(repr(result))


def main():
    # open a workbook (adapt your filename)
    # then get the first sheet (index 0)
    # and call the process function
    wbook = xlrd.open_workbook('/tmp/test.xlsx')
    sheet = wbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    process_sheet(sheet)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```